# Is it an undefined behavior that the return type of a coroutine doesn't own a member type: promise_type in C++20 standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, coroutine, c++-coroutine

In the C++ Technical Specification [N4680](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4680.pdf), 8.4.4.3 writes:

> For a coroutine f that is a non-static member function, let P1 denote the type of the implicit
>   object parameter (13.3.1) and P2 ... Pn be the types of the function parameters; otherwise
>   let P1 ... Pn be the types of the function parameters. Let p1 ... pn be lvalues denoting
>   those objects. Let R be the return type and F be the function-body of f, T be the type
>   std::experimental::coroutine_traits, and P be the class type denoted by
>   T::promise_type. Then, the coroutine behaves as if its body were:

This paragraph seems like that every coroutine should have a promise type. But in 18.11.1.1, it says:

> 1 The header  defines the primary template coroutine_traits such
>   that if ArgTypes is a parameter pack of types and if R is a type that has a valid (14.8.2) member
>   type promise_type, then coroutine_traits has the following publicly
>   accessible member:

```
using promise_type = typename R::promise_type;
```

> Otherwise, coroutine_traits has no members.

It seems like that it is legal that the `coroutine_traits<R,ArgTypes...>` would not own a `promise_type`.

So it is confusing me that whether it is an undefined behavior that the return type of a corouinte don't own a `promise_type`.

---

Another related question: is there other place to ask question about the standard of C++? I feel it is a little strange to ask these question in Stackoverflow.

Comment: https://lists.isocpp.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/std-discussion ?

Comment: @underscore_d thank you! I will give it a try.